# every continuously differentiable function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is every continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous?

I think no, but am unable to find any counterexample. Any idea. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: No. $x\mapsto x^2$ e.g.

Comment: @OpenBall oh, thanks. It was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comment by Open Ball, there exists several such functions which are continuously differentiable, but not uniformly continuous. Few of them, being:$x^n,n\ge2; \sin x^n,n\ge2; e^{x^n},n\ge2$etc.